# Jquery UI Spinner - UI V1.8.10

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like to use the new Jquery UI Spinner widget on a website. My problem is that the website already uses jquery UI 1.8.10 and when I tried updating to 1.9 I got a lot of errors due to other plugins relying on V 1.8.

Is it possible to load the spinner widget on a page that has already loaded jquery ui 1.8? Is it possible to load jquery ui 1.9 in tandem so I can then load the spinner widget? Is it possible to modify the spinner widget to work with 1.8? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a quick fiddle of the spinner I want to use (selects hours and minutes and steps by half hours) - http://jsfiddle.net/fDpE9/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make a JavaScript function to create my own widget without jQuery UI. I added a create function to replace the input with the same HTML as a Jquery UI spinner, and attach my own spin function to the button clicks. Still need to add holding mouse down event on the buttons but you get the idea.

```
function createHourMinSpinner(elementSelector) {
    $(elementSelector).replaceWith('<span class="ui-spinner ui-state-default ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><input id="' + $(elementSelector).attr('id') + '" class="ui-spinner-input" value="' + $(elementSelector).val() + '" name="' + $(elementSelector).attr('name') + '" style="width:' + $(elementSelector).width() + 'px;" aria-valuenow="0" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton"><a onclick="spinHourMin(\'#' + $(elementSelector).attr('id') + '\', true);" class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">▲</span></span></a><a onclick="spinHourMin(\'#' + $(elementSelector).attr('id') + '\', false);" class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">▼</span></span></a>');
}

function spinHourMin(elementSelector, goingUp) {
    var originalVal = $(elementSelector).val() + "";
    var originalWhole = parseInt(originalVal.split(':')[0]);
    var originalFract = parseInt(originalVal.split(':')[1]);
    var newValue = "0:00";

    if (!goingUp && originalWhole == 0) {
        newValue = "0:00";
    } else if (goingUp && (originalFract == undefined || originalFract < 30 || isNaN(originalFract))) {
        newValue = originalWhole + ":30";
    } else if (goingUp && originalFract >= 30) {
        newValue = (originalWhole + 1) + ":00";
    } else if (!goingUp && (originalFract == undefined || originalFract == 0 || isNaN(originalFract))) {
        newValue = (originalWhole - 1) + ":30";
    } else if (!goingUp && originalFract > 30) {
        newValue = originalWhole + ":30";
    } else if (!goingUp && originalFract <= 30 && originalFract != 0 && originalFract != undefined) {
        newValue = originalWhole + ":00";
    }

    $(elementSelector).val(newValue);
}
```